# How to do an advanced search in php?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I want to do a form so that users of a library can do an advanced search. I thought I could use the values hard coded in my form and append them to the query (they come from select fields). I also thought how to do this with the minimum code possible, so I do an explode in case someone selects (words) (that is, search words instead of phrases). My final code goes like:

```
<?php 

    /** 
     *  this variable is the result of the user    
     *  selecting 'word' or 'phrase'
    **/ 
    $coleccion = implode('&', $keysres);

    $contents_1 = array();
    $contents_2 = array();
    $contents_3 = array();

    $words_1 = array();
    $words_2 = array();
    $words_3 = array();

    switch ($coleccion) {

    case 'palabras&palabras&palabras': 

        $contents_1 = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $buscar_1);

        foreach ($contents_1 as $word) {
            array_push($words_1, " MATCH ($contenido_1) AGAINST ('$word') ");
        }

        $contents_2 = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $buscar_2);

        foreach ($contents_2 as $word) {
            array_push($words_2, " MATCH ($contenido_2) AGAINST ('$word') ");
        }

        $contents_3 = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $buscar_3);

        foreach ($contents_3 as $word) {
            array_push($words_3, " MATCH ($contenido_3) AGAINST ('$word') ");
        }

        $search_words_1 = implode(" OR ", $words_1);
        $search_words_2 = implode(" OR ", $words_2);
        $search_words_3 = implode(" OR ", $words_3);

        $consulta = "
                SELECT * 
                FROM catalogo 
                WHERE 
                   $search_words_1 ". 
                   $oper_1 
                   ." $search_words_2 ". 
                   $oper_2 ." 
                   $search_words_3 ";
    break;

?>
```

The problem is that when I change the values of the select fields, say someone chooses to do an  OR operation instead of an AND, and chooses to do a phrase search for the second of my text fields, in such cases, I do not see the search being restricted or widened. For example I do a variable dump with the case of `$coleccion=palabras&frase&palabras` and I do a var_dump of the query, then it shows: `SELECT * FROM catalogo WHERE MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('mesones') OR MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('y') OR MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('bariones') OR MATCH(titulo) AGAINST('mesones y totems') AND MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('bariones')`

So my question is ¿what is the correct way of limiting / widening searches in SQL? Unfortunately I don't have too many entries on the database to test with.

Finally, I also have set things so that queries that try to get all records "except" some end up with this syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM catalogo WHERE MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('comunicaciones') OR MATCH  (titulo) AGAINST ('y') OR MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('poder') AND NOT MATCH(titulo) AGAINST('mesones') AND NOT MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('bariones')
```

But I wonder if such a query really excludes the records specified. Or should I use the leading minus in BOOLEAN mode, according to this:

> A leading minus sign indicates that this word must not be present in
>   any of the rows that are returned.
>   Note: The - operator acts only to exclude rows that are otherwise
>   matched by other search terms. Thus, a boolean-mode search that
>   contains only terms preceded by - returns an empty result. It does not
>   return “all rows except those containing any of the excluded terms.

I think I now have an example about what I'm doubting. Suppose the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM catalogo WHERE MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('comunicaciones') OR MATCH     (titulo) AGAINST ('y') OR MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('poder') AND MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('mesones') OR MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('y') OR MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('totems') AND NOT MATCH(titulo) AGAINST('bariones')
```

Then I guess that should show all records with the words 'comunicaciones', 'y' and 'poder' as well as those with the word 'mesones' and 'y' and 'totems', yet not show those with the ord 'bariones'. 
However the result of that query is only those with the word comunicaciones in my DB

Comment: If you really want to do an "advanced" search, you should consider using a specialised search tool for the database such as Sphinx rather than trying to get mySQL to do it on its own.

Comment: @Spudley Thanks Spudley I'll check that out and decide if it's worth the shot.